# How to remain on the same page if error occured?

Tags: php

The following code is simplified to illustrate my question.  This is a page to capture data and it will will post the captured info and pass to another php page for processing.  I'm trying to ensure the required fields are entered but it always go to the calling page regardless there is error.
Can anyone help?

```
<?php
  if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_field = array('first_name','last_name');
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_field) === true) {
      $errors[] = 'Fields marked with asterisk are required';
      break 1;
      }
    }
  }
?>
<h1>Input Form</h1>

<?php
  if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
  }
?>

<form method="POST" action="UpdateDB.php" name="UpdateForm">
   <input type=text size="19" maxlength="19" name="firstname">
   <input type=text size="19" maxlength="19" name="lastname">   
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: this `if (empty($errors) === false)` and `if(!empty($errors))` is same  than why first ?

Comment: is this script `updatedb.php`? if not, then you're submitting to some OTHER script and the error handling code will never be invoked.

Comment: Is this `UpdateDB.php` or is that your other script? If it is the other one, then yes absolutely the form will always post to there.

Comment: Sorry for confusion.  This is another script.  Original sample is one page to capture data and post to another page for processing.  However the sample of data capturing page doesn't validate.

Comment: I'm new with php.  I did one similar but the form posts back to itself for database update (without action="xxx").  I don't know how to do in this way but I definitely need to post data to another form as it's hard to transfer the logic back to the calling page. Hope somene can help.

Comment: So it there any means to remain on the same page until error free?

Comment: Please go through my answer. I've tried to make it as detailed as I could.

Answer (score 0):

Either submit the form to the current page by leaving an empty `action` attribute (and do the processing here), or add a hidden field with the current page URL:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sourceUrl" value="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
```

Then in your `UpdateDB.php` script redirect back to this URL if there are errors. Something like:

```
$url = $_POST['sourceUrl']; // <- sanitize this (make sure it's your site)!

header('Status-Code: 301');
header('Location: http:// ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $url); 
exit; // important: stop current script
```

Comment: So the first part is to (1) empty action attribute and (2) add the hidden url.  Where do I check the error? source and destination page?

Comment: No, you misunderstood. These are two ways of doing this: by having an empty action and check for your error on the same page (this way the form will always be submitted to the current page), **or** by leaving the processing in the other script and use the hidden field to redirect back

Comment: I tried to use a hidden field to store the url and check the _POST variable in the called page.  It is now able to return back to the calling page but then how do I get the error back in the calling page.  Do I use echo to send back a hidden field about the error?

Comment: You could store the error messages in a session. Or pass the errors as codes to the Url like `?error=5`, then in your other script display a message based on the `$_GET['error']` code

Answer (score 0):

Below code will check whether the page is called using POST Method, If not it will print the Input Form.

the php script must be stored in UpdateDB.php,

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_POST)){

    echo "<h1>Input Form</h1>";
    echo "<form method="POST" action="UpdateDB.php" name="UpdateForm"> <br/>" .
       "<input type=text size="19" maxlength="19" name="firstname"> <br/>" .
       "<input type=text size="19" maxlength="19" name="lastname">   <br/>" .
       "<input type="submit" value="Submit" >" .
    "</form>";
    }

    else{
         /*Form Action code goes here*/
          }
        }
    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute:

```html
<form method="POST" action="UpdateDB.php" name="UpdateForm">
   <input required type=text size="19" maxlength="19" name="firstname">
   <input required type=text size="19" maxlength="19" name="lastname">   
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```